# Entity framework 4.3

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

Hi i am using Entity framework 4.3.

I had a table "Notes" in which **NoteId** is primary key(data type is int). I generated value for NoteId like this by using stored procedure..

```
 notes.NoteId = (int)dbContext.GeneratePrimaryKey("Notes");
```

When i am inserting data to the table "**Notes**" it raises that null value cannot be inserted into noteid. But the noteid is generated.

Can any one please help me to solve the issue....

Comment: Is NoteId being mapped properly back to the database?  Did it used to be called something else, like Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your mapping expects that the primary key is autogenerated in the database. In such case your value will not be used. Verify that in your EDMX the `NoteId` property has `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `None`.